# How to check if my remote git credentials are correct without changing state

Tags: bash, git, bitbucket

I'm writing a fairly long bash script and at the start of it I need to know if the provided username and password arguments for a remote git repo are correct. The remote repo is in bitbucket if that makes a difference. I can't check the credentials by using something like git fetch at this point as that would change the state of the local repo which I want to avoid.

Rough minimal example:

```
git remote set-url origin https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/account-name/repo-name.git
if !$(has read permissions from git remote origin); then
  echo "Error, provided git credentials are incorrect"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Git fetch option `--dry-run Show what would be done, without making any changes.`

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need, thanks man

Comment: Another option is : `git ls-remote <url>`. That one can even be run from outside a repo.

Comment: Feel free to post either of these as an answer guys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+check+credentials